# Determine which of the following statements are true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am doing some mathematics, and I am currently stuck on something. I do not understand this part at all:

Let $A=\{1,\{1\},\{2\},3,\{3\}\}$. Determine, and explain in your own words, which of the following statements are true:

**i)** $\{2\} \subseteq A$

**ii)** $1 \subseteq A$

**iii)** $\{1\} \in A$

**iv)** $3 \in A$

My Solution:

**i)** *TRUE*.

**ii)** *FALSE*.

**iii)** *TRUE*.

**iv)** *TRUE*.

---

Why isn't the following $\{2\} \subseteq A$ **true**? Instead in the solution paper by the teacher it is **False**. With a short explanation:

> Since the set A doesn't contain the element 2

But, I see $\{2\}$ in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, if $A$ is a set, then $$\{a\}\subseteq A$$ is true **if and only if** $$a\in A$$ is true.

In your case, therefore, $\{2\}\subseteq A$ can only be true if $2\in A$ is true, but $2\in A$ is **not** true. $A$ contains exactly $5$ elements, and **none** of them is equal to $2$.

Note that one of them is $\{2\}$, but $\{2\}$ and $2$ are two different things!

Comment: What a fantastic and easy to understand explanation. Thank you so much.